# tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden using Twitter API v2 functions in Tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am just starting out with using Tweepy and have been having trouble when trying to use the v2 API functions to write a program to Tweet text. Currently, I am getting this error repeatedly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\Twitter Bot\Twitter Bot.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = client.create_tweet(text='Hello!')
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\Twitter Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 594, in create_tweet
    return self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\Twitter Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 118, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\Twitter Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 92, in request
    raise Forbidden(response)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

Here is my current code:

```
import tweepy
import config

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=config.api_key,
    consumer_secret=config.api_secret,
    access_token=config.access_token,
    access_token_secret=config.access_secret
)

response = client.create_tweet(text='Hello!')

print(response)
```

I have tried regenerating my tokens and keys a few times now, with similar results. I have also tried searching online for other users who have encountered this error, but haven't had much luck finding anything besides others using v1 functions by mistake.

Is there anything I can do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to give your app write permission:

> Why am I encountering a 401 Unauthorized error with `API` or 403 Forbidden error with `Client`?
>
> If you’re using a method that performs an action on behalf of the authenticating user, e.g. `API.update_status()`, make sure your app has the write permission.
>
> After giving it the write permission, make sure to regenerate and use new credentials to utilize it.
>
> See [Twitter’s API documentation on app permissions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions) for more information.

https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error-with-api-or-403-forbidden-error-with-client

Comment: This helped a lot! Turns out I was just giving my access tokens Read permissions instead of Read and Write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to your application by including the `user_auth=True` parameter so that it looks something like this:

```
import tweepy
import config

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=config.api_key,
    consumer_secret=config.api_secret,
    access_token=config.access_token,
    access_token_secret=config.access_secret,
    user_auth=True
)

response = client.create_tweet(text='Hello!')

print(response)
```

Comment: This code does not work. There is no such parameter for tweepy.Client(): https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html